# Change a property of an object inside the Redux state object

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've got to create a React + Redux app that is basically a movie database management app. For now, only viewing movie details, deleting a movie and logging in (to be able to delete that movie) is possible. I've set an initial state with 3 movies in it and some basic data of a user are available. The user object contains the following fields: isLoggedIn, nickname and password (I'm saving these last 2 in state because I don't use any APIs to get data from a server or anything similar). On Login, the state object user should change its isLoggedIn field to true (default is false) and display the delete button.

The question is: how to change the isLoggedIn from true to false while keeping the rest of the user object and the rest of the Store intact?

Here's what I tried so far ( I haven't finished with the switch yet, I know I have to set a default):

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

const initialState = {
    movies: [
        { id: '1', movie_title: 'John Wick Chapter 2', year: '2017', main_actor: 'Keanu Reeves', summary: `The hitman that's been retired then back then retired strikes again, this time against the Mafia.`, cover: '%PUBLIC_URL%/john_wick_2.png' },
        { id: '2', movie_title: 'Star Wars Revenge of the Sith', year: '2005', main_actor: 'Ewan McGregor', summary: `Anakin betrays Space Jesus so General Kenobi is forced to Mustafar Anakin.`, cover: '%PUBLIC_URL%/sw_rots.png' },
        { id: '3', movie_title: 'Star Wars The Clone Wars', year: '2008 - 2020', main_actor: 'Ewan McGregor, Hayden Christensen', summary: `Yoda has finally overdosed on Ketamine, Mace Window hasn't been defenestrated yet and The Negotiator has proven himself incapable of falling to the Dark Side`, cover: '%PUBLIC_URL%/sw_tcw.png' }
    ],
    user: {
        isLoggedIn: 'false',
        nickname: 'obi_wan',
        password: '12345'
    }
}

const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){ 
        case(action.type === 'DELETE_MOVIE'):
            let newMovieList = state.movies.filter(movie => {
            return action.id !== movie.id
        })
            return {
                ...state,
                movies: newMovieList
            }
        case(action.type === 'LOG_IN'):
            let newUser = ...user, action.isLoggedIn
            return (
                ...state, 
                user: Object.assign(user, action.isLoggedIn);
            )
    }
    return state;
}
```

Here's the movieActions and userActions:

```
export const loginAction = (isLoggedIn) => {
    return {
        type: 'LOG_IN',
        isLoggedIn: 'true'
    }
}

export const deleteMovieAction = (id) => {
    return {
        type: 'DELETE_MOVIE',
        id
    }
}
```

And here's the project on GitHub:
https://github.com/liviu-ganea/movie-database

Answer (score 1):

```js
const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){ 
        case(action.type === 'DELETE_MOVIE'):
            let newMovieList = state.movies.filter(movie => {
            return action.id !== movie.id
        })
            return {
                ...state,
                movies: newMovieList
            }
        case(action.type === 'LOG_IN'):
            return (
                ...state, 
                user: {
                   ...state.user,
                   isLoggedIn: action.isLoggedIn,
               }
            )
    }
    return state;
}
```

Like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use spread operator, remember that action should have just a type and a payload so it could be better to put your params in a payload object.

```
return ({
  ...state,
  user: {
    ...state.user,
    isLoggedIn: action.payload.isLoggedIn
})
```